# i get a run time error 1004 while running vba

Tags: vba

i am really knew to excel and am having some problems.  i am trying to create an attendance sheet where for safety reasons which gets updated periodically throughout the day.  on a sheet with all the possible names i have a column for different companies, names, camp, room, and on site.  i have written my code so that if a person is on site than a 1 goes in the on site column and a 0 if they are off site.  when a 1 appears i want their name and all other information to transfer to the attendance sheet so that the only names that appear are the ones that are on site.  if they are on site i want the space to be left blank.
i have two problems with my code:

```
Sub onsite()

    x = 3   'start at row 3


    'start the loop
    Do While Cells(x, 6) <> ""

        'look for data with '1'
        If Cells(x, 6) = "1" Then

        'copy the row if it contains '1'
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).Copy

        'go to main ERP.  activate it
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

        **erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row**
        'paste data

         '**ERROR OCCURS HERE**
         ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(erow)

         End If

         'go to all names and activate
         Worksheets("AllNames").Activate

         'loop through the other rows
         x = x + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

The first problem is that after i reach the bold line i get an error '1004' message and the code stops working

The other problem is that i dont know how to change 'erow=' into code that skips a row when a person has 0 in their on site column

please help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub onsite()
    Dim x as long, erow as Long
    Dim shtSrc as Worksheet, shtDest as worksheet

    Set shtSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    erow = shtDest.Cells(rows.count, 6).End(xlUp).Row+1

    x = 3       

    Do While shtSrc.Cells(x, 6) <> ""

        If shtSrc.Cells(x, 6) = "1" Then

            shtSrc.Rows(x).Copy shtDest.cells(erow,1)
            erow = erow+1

        End If
        x = x + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[This MS Knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905164) describes the cause of the error and a workaround.

Basically it's a problem when programmatically copying and pasting an entire row. You have to select only the cells in the row that are actually used.